# Can't access some clients using w32tm /stripchart - error: 0x800705B4

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-controller, time-synchronization, w32time

I'm trying to track down a time synchronisation problem.  I've got a DC in a remote branch.
w32tm /dumpreg /subkey:Parameters reveals Type = NT5DS and the Type means its sync'ing with the domain, I understand.  I've checked using: w32tm /stripchart /dataonly /samples:5 /computer:core-fsmo-dc and it's in sync.

I can run the same command against other DCs and some devices but others (including other servers in the branch and elsewhere) give me:

```
Tracking server1 [w.x.y.z].
Collecting 5 samples.
The current time is 01/09/2009 13:46:01 (local time).
13:46:01, error: 0x800705B4
13:46:04, error: 0x800705B4
13:46:07, error: 0x800705B4
13:46:10, error: 0x800705B4
13:46:13, error: 0x800705B4
```

I'm logged onto the branch DC when I run these commands and my account is in the Builtin domain Administrators group.

Can anyone explain why I can't get access to some devices and what this error means?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;Q216734  Is the article on how to set it up right.

The error is coming from the fact the query is timing out. The reason for the timeout is not clear to me given the information you have provided.  However if I understand everything you're saying I am pretty sure things are working as designed.

Experimentation in my environment seems to indicate that you get the error response when you try and query things that are not serving up NTP. When you run the query against things that are NTP time hosts regardless of if you're using them or not you can get a response. For example try querying www.google.com and time.nist.gov. I think the command is working as intended. You should from a member server be able to query the DC and get a time response, or from a workstation. One truly hopes that your member servers and workstations are not serving NTP up.

```
Tracking not-a-timeserver [xxx.xxx.x.123].
Collecting 5 samples.
The current time is 9/1/2009 5:30:40 PM (local time).
17:30:40, error: 0x800705B4
17:30:43, error: 0x800705B4
17:30:46, error: 0x800705B4
17:30:49, error: 0x800705B4
17:30:52, error: 0x800705B4

Tracking a-domain-controller [xxx.xxx.x.2].
Collecting 5 samples.
The current time is 9/1/2009 5:31:06 PM (local time).
17:31:06, +02.4314759s
17:31:08, +02.4319879s
17:31:10, +02.4324999s
17:31:12, +02.4330119s
17:31:14, +02.4335239s

Tracking stratum1-ntp-appliance [xxx.xxx.x.101].
Collecting 5 samples.
The current time is 9/1/2009 5:36:03 PM (local time).
17:36:03, +25.8268797s
17:36:05, +25.8201250s
17:36:07, +25.8210791s
17:36:09, +25.8211743s
17:36:11, +25.8216523s
```

Comment: Ah, I see.  You're saying the command can only be run from the client to the time server: it's comparing the local time with the time 'broadcast' (for want of a better term) by the time service.  I'd misunderstood: I thought it was simply comparing local and remote times using the time services on the machines.  How irritating.  For various reasons, I can't simply run the command from the clients.